# How to get timeout configuration from Hystrix using HystrixCommandKey

Tags: java, hystrix, fallback

I register a custom HystrixEventNotifier, from which I can catch the fallback event, and report some log, but it will be better if I can get the timeout configuration of the HystrixCommand, but we only have HystrixCommandKey in HystrixEventNotifier, so is there a way to get the timeout configuration from HystrixCommandKey? code example of HystrixEventNotifier:

```
public void markEvent(HystrixEventType eventType, HystrixCommandKey key) {
    // do nothing
}
```